# How to make the background of an image ( logo ) transparent in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've an image ( logo ) and I would like to pass it as an argument and make the background transparent and then save it.

How can I achieve this ?

This what I've tried :

```
public string SaveImage(Bitmap bmp,string SavePath,string Name)
    {
        string path = "";
        var format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        using (var m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(m, format);

            var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(m);


            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) // This is what I've used for making the background transparent 
            {
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
                g.Save();
            }
            var ImgPath = Path.Combine(SavePath, Path.ChangeExtension(Name,"png"));

            img.Save(ImgPath);
            path = ImgPath;

        }

        return path;
    }
```

After testing this function I'm getting a black image as an output ( save image )

Comment: This is WinForms code. Why is the question tagged as WPF?

Comment: I'm using this code for WPF , this function is already worked in WPF ( except what I've added in the block `using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) // This is what I've used for making the background transparent 
            {
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
                g.Save();
            }`

Comment: Separating the background from foreground is not trivial. You need to process each pixel and have some way to determine if it is part of the background or foreground. Your current example does not even attempt such a thing.

Comment: @JonasH , sorry but I've made some search and that's what I've found in the community so I've tried it .

Comment: Your example should simply create an image that is fully transparent. If you want help you should probably show some examples. In the trivial case where the background has only a single color there is [MakeTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent?view=netframework-4.8#system-drawing-bitmap-maketransparent(system-drawing-color)), But there is no way to know if this would work without seeing some example images.

Comment: You should actually be creating a WPF BitmapSource with a PixelFormat that has an alpha channel. Then process and copy the raw pixel buffer as needed.

Comment: What's your logo look like? If it's one colour then I'd trace to vector geometry using inkscape and use a path instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks for your code:

- You use `System.Drawing` types wrapping native GDI+ components, not WPF.
- You save the `Bitmap` with JPEG encoder, which does not support transparency. Even if the logo had a transparent background it is removed by the JPEG encoder
- Now you reload the saved image and clear the complete content with transparent color (which will not work either as the reloaded JPEG image will have 24-bit RGB pixel format without alpha support so the whole image will be black)

Possible solutions:

- Use PNG encoder instead, which supports transparency. If the logo had a transparent background you don't even need anything else.
- If the logo was not transparent originally, use the [`MakeTransparent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent) method instead of `Clear`. It will replace a single color so it is not able to restore possible anti-aliased alpha blending. It will also convert the pixel format so can be used also on the reloaded JPEG.
- To do the same in WPF you can use [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) library (disclaimer: written by me). You can use the [`GetReadWriteBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Wpf_WriteableBitmapExtensions_GetReadWriteBitmapData.htm) extension method on a `WriteableBitmap` to access the same [`MakeTransparent`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/Overload_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataExtensions_MakeTransparent.htm) functionality as above along with a sort of [other features](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataExtensions.htm). But to restore a nicely anti-aliased alpha background you might want to use the [`TransformColors`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataExtensions_TransformColors_1.htm) method instead if you know how to separate the blended colors.

Comment: Thank for your answer , actually for now I wouldn't like to use third party packages , I'm searching for a trick or method developed by Microsoft

Comment: For MS solutions the first two bullet points can solve your issue if you use GDI+ `Bitmap` in your project. A PNG stream can be simply reloaded as a WPF `BitmapImage`. MS did not provide such features for WPF images so if you want to do it yourself you need to reimplement something similar to my solution (the code is open source, feel free to get ideas - the license is quite permissive). Btw. referencing NuGet packages is quite a standard way of using libraries today.

Answer (score 0):

Change background Color by code below

```
                   using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])(bits)))
                        {
                            var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                            
                            using (var b = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height))
                            {
                                b.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

                                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                                {
                                    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                                    g.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
                                }
                                // Encoder parameter for image quality
                                EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                                // Jpeg image codec
                                ImageCodecInfo imgcodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/" + ImageFormat.Png.ToString().ToLower());

                                EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                                encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
                                b.Save(target, imgcodec, encoderParams);
                            }
                        }
```